# Firefox is always going to java site for updated version

Tags: firefox, java, plugins

I had clicked on "always perform the task" and now Firefox is directing to Java site whenever I am trying to download in keepvid. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter `about:config` in the address bar, then press the "**I'll be careful, I promise!**" button.
2. Enter `blocklist` in the "**Filter:**" text box, then double click the "**extensions.blocklist.enabled**" entry so its value changes to "**false**".
3. Go to **Tools** -> **Add-ons**, then **Plugins**. Enable the Java plugin if it is disabled.